Read data from a barcode reade using Python in Linux Ubuntu
I need just to read data from a barcode plugged in usb port. I am using Linux Ubuntu 24.04 with Python but I have no idea how to do this. I read a lot of docs but no one is straight forward enough or doesn't work for my application.
I will be very grateful for help.

You need to describe way more your problem. The barcode is plugged into USB port? Or you have a barcode reader? Which one. What the doc says? Is there a provided API? (Most barcode readers I have seen just behave as keyboard. So, no need for any API, nor driver. Just input().)

Does this help you?

You need to check the documentation for your barcode reader to see what data it presents. Many such devices return the data as text characters.

@chrslg I did not thought this before, but has work nice. Thank you. Too much simple.

I do not know what barcode you mean but I will try to help. To read a barcode as shown below:

you can use many libraries to do that:
You can refer to this linked article:

https://blog.jonasneubert.com/2022/09/30/the-best-python-packages-for-reading-barcodes/


Recommended Package
zxing-cpp is the best Python package for reading barcodes.

the article advises not to use pure Python to read barcodes

Don’t use Python for Barcode Decoding!
You really shouldn’t be using pure Python to decode barcodes from images or videos or, worse, from camera streams.

and, the article talks about a lot of libraries and recommends using zxing-cpp
You can install it using pip
pip install zxing-cpp
You should also install openCV
pip install opencv-python
after that, you can use code similar to following to read a barcode:
import cv2, zxingcpp

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
results = zxingcpp.read_barcodes(img)
for result in results:
    print('Found barcode:'
        f'\n Text:    "{result.text}"'
        f'\n Format:   {result.format}'
        f'\n Content:  {result.content_type}'
        f'\n Position: {result.position}')
if len(results) == 0:
    print("Could not find any barcode.")

the output:
Found barcode:
 Text:    "1234567890128"
 Format:   BarcodeFormat.EAN13
 Content:  ContentType.Text
 Position: 76x11 446x11 446x188 76x188


Are you consider 'test.png' as a file with barcode image?

@Angelo yes it is a file containing this barcode https://i.sstatic.net/KPX0p8YG.png
